# How to select a product by tag in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of products, each product has an array of tags. I need to select products with specific tags, for example, sale. Array example:

```
[
    {
        "tags": [
            {   
                "name": "Hit",
                "slug": "hit",
            },
            {
                "name": "Sale",
                "slug": "sale",
            }
        ],
        "price": 6000,
        "stock": 10,
        "name": "Name Product",
        "description": "Test",
        "slug": "name-product",
    }, 
    {
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Sale",
                "slug": "sale",
            }
        ],
        "price": 6000,
        "stock": 10,
        "name": "Name Product 2",
        "description": "Test 2",
        "slug": "name-product-2",
    }
]
```

I will be grateful!

Comment: show what you have tried so far ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts:

1. use `.filter` to filter the array based on a function, [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
2. use `.find` to check whether each item has your desired property, in this case, a tag with the name `sales`, [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const array = [
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: "Hit",
        slug: "hit"
      },
      {
        name: "Sale",
        slug: "sale"
      }
    ],
    price: 6000,
    stock: 10,
    name: "Name Product",
    description: "Test",
    slug: "name-product"
  },
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: "Sale",
        slug: "sale"
      }
    ],
    price: 6000,
    stock: 10,
    name: "Name Product 2",
    description: "Test 2",
    slug: "name-product-2"
  },
  {
    tags: [
      {
        name: "NotSale",
        slug: "notsale"
      }
    ],
    price: 6000,
    stock: 10,
    name: "Name Product 2",
    description: "Test 2",
    slug: "name-product-2"
  }
];

const filteredArray = array.filter((t) => {
  return t.tags && t.tags.find((tag) => tag.name.toLowerCase() === "sale");
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```